# Ansibleのyumモジュールでwith_itemsパラメータを使用する方法について

Tags: vagrant, ansible

Vagrantからansible_localプロビジョナーで
下記のAnsibleスクリプトを動かしたところ

```
- name: install
  yum:
    name: $item
    state: latest
    with_items:
      - gcc
      - make
      - git
      - openssl-devel
      - bzip2-devel
      - zlib-devel
      - readline-devel
      - sqlite-devel
      - patch
```

下記のようなエラーがでました。

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => 
{
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (yum) module: with_items. Supported parameters include: conf_file,disable_gpg_check,disablerepo,enablerepo,exclude,install_repoquery,installroot,list,name,skip_broken,state,update_cache,validate_certs"
}
```

エラー文言をみるにyumモジュールではwith_itemsパラメータが使用できないとのことですが、
テックブログなどをみるに、どうやら動くと書いてあるところが多かったので動作すると思っているのですが、
yumモジュールではwith_itemsパラメータは使えないのでしょうか？
上記のコードのエラー原因などご教授いただけると幸いです。

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.3.1.0
```

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

手元に実行端末がないので、半分あてずっぽうですが、

```
- name: install
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - gcc
    - make
    - git
    - openssl-devel
    - bzip2-devel
    - zlib-devel
    - readline-devel
    - sqlite-devel
    - patch
```

ではないでしょうか。

変更点:

- `with_items` は `yum` につくのではなく、 task 自体に紐付ける。
- `$item` -> `"{{ item }}"`